# Is winrscmde good or bad?

Tags: spyware, svchost

Is svchost running with a description of "winrscmde" good or bad? Is it spyware? Malwarebytes and windows security essensials report two trojans found, but they don't say that is winrscmde. I booted Microsoft Windows defender offline which used to be called microsoft system sweeper and it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's not good. It is [bad](http://www.pchelpforum.com/progress-hijackthis-logs/128528-help-getting-rid-svchost-exe-32-description-winrscmde.html) and a [threat](http://systemexplorer.net/filereviews.php?fid=1371840). I don't *think* this is the forum for getting specific removal advice (someone correct me if I'm wrong), you should check out google for some help on finding a forum that will analyze your logs and help you remove it.

Additionally, you should back up (if you haven't already) all vital data.